# Is it possible to change the color of sublayer on PDF format in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

Is it possible to change the color of the sublayer in pdf format in Xcode?

I've found a way to change the tint color(while rendering as a template image), but it's changing the color for the whole image.

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I need:**

[image]